# Error on building a model "no member found for key ... but dimension has an "Unknown member" (icCube)

Tags: builder, iccube

Not sure if I am doing something wrong. But in the BUILDER I defined a dimension with the "Unknown Member" field set to 'Unknown'. The facts table - based on an in memory file - has some empty values for the key that is used.

Now I expect icCube to use the 'Unknown' member for these when the schema is deployed and loaded but I get the error message:

> Data table 'Changes', line '2' : The column 'priorityId' has no value in the facts table (hint: null foreign key)

(I understand the error, that is why I have the "Unknown Member" set in the dimension).

When I set the 'If Null/ Empty' field in the selected table to a value, for example 'aap' and I deploy and load, I get the error message:

> Data table 'Changes', line '2' : Processing facts 'Cube.Facts', no member found for key 'aap' in dimension 'ChangePriorities' and level 'name' - fact key column(s) = 'priorityId'.

(Also, this specific situation (a member that is not present in the dimension) should have been taken care of by setting the "Unknown Member".)
Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you missed the property 'Use Unknown Members in Facts' in Properties

[image: icCcube snapshot 2]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes I did. I completely missed that setting. Thank you.